# Problems w/ PyCluster

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a follow python code:

```
  from Pycluster import *
  from numpy import *
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   names = [ "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", 
             "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15"]

   distances = array([
   [0.000, 0.840, 0.860, 0.115, 0.150, 0.055, 0.000, 0.070, 0.065, 0.000, 0.165, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.065],
   [0.840, 0.000, 0.710, 0.060, 0.125, 0.060, 0.000, 0.070, 0.065, 0.000, 0.165, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.070],
   [0.860, 0.710, 0.000, 0.055, 0.120, 0.055, 0.000, 0.070, 0.065, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.065],
   [0.115, 0.060, 0.055, 0.000, 0.885, 0.455, 0.415, 0.060, 0.150, 0.050, 0.240, 0.000, 0.000, 0.065, 0.140],
   [0.150, 0.125, 0.120, 0.885, 0.000, 0.510, 0.330, 0.125, 0.165, 0.050, 0.145, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.200],
   [0.055, 0.060, 0.055, 0.455, 0.510, 0.000, 0.335, 0.060, 0.215, 0.050, 0.140, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.085],
   [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.415, 0.330, 0.335, 0.000, 0.000, 0.245, 0.060, 0.255, 0.125, 0.000, 0.075, 0.225],
   [0.070, 0.070, 0.070, 0.060, 0.125, 0.060, 0.000, 0.000, 0.195, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.140],
   [0.065, 0.065, 0.065, 0.150, 0.165, 0.215, 0.245, 0.195, 0.000, 0.045, 0.135, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.155],
   [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.050, 0.050, 0.050, 0.060, 0.000, 0.045, 0.000, 0.000, 0.120, 0.000, 0.045, 0.080],
   [0.165, 0.165, 0.000, 0.240, 0.145, 0.140, 0.255, 0.000, 0.135, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.150, 0.150],
   [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.125, 0.000, 0.000, 0.120, 0.000, 0.000, 0.175, 0.090, 0.105],
   [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.175, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
   [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.065, 0.000, 0.000, 0.075, 0.000, 0.000, 0.045, 0.150, 0.090, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
   [0.065, 0.070, 0.065, 0.140, 0.200, 0.085, 0.225, 0.140, 0.155, 0.080, 0.150, 0.105, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
   ])

   clusterids, error, nfound = kmedoids(distances, 6)
   print "Cluster ids:", clusterids
   print "error:", error
   print "nfound:", nfound

   cities_in_cluster = {}
   for name, clusterid in zip(names, clusterids):
        cities_in_cluster.setdefault(clusterid, []).append(name)

   import textwrap
   for centroid_id, city_names in cities_in_cluster.items():
        print "Cluster around", names[centroid_id]
        text = ", ".join(city_names)
        for line in textwrap.wrap(text, 70):
             print "  ", line

   colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'white', 'black']

   medoids = {}  
   for i in clusterids:
        medoids[i]= medoids.get(i,0) + 1    

   plt.scatter(distances[:,0],distances[:,1], c=colors)
   plt.show()
```

This code presents two problems:
- every execution gives a different clustering result. Is it right?
- the graph is plotting only 11 points, instead 15 points.

Where is the errors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`kmedoids` uses *random* initialization, and may converge to *local* minima.

So yes, you can get different results if you run it multiple times.

Any chance your distance matrix *are not distances*?

You have **too many 0 values there**.

The row

```
[0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.175, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
```

is an extreme example. By looking at your matrix, **all points are essentially identical**, because from any one point you can find a chain of 0 distances to any other point! Thus, **your matrix is not a distance matrix**. This violation of basic distance properties likely kills `kmedoids` and causes it to return essentially random results?

Also, **do not scatter plot a distance matrix**. Scatter plots are used on the *input* data, not on the first two rows of the distance matrix. If you want to reconstruct a scatterplot from the distance matrix, use *multidimensional scaling*.

Comment: well the matrix would make sense as distances (though maybe the zeros are interpreted as 'not connected') in which case all the points are discrete. What doesn't make sense is to use the distance of An to A1as the x coordinate and the distance of An to A2 as the y coordinate in a scatter plot!

Comment: Well, if 0 means "not connected", then it is *not* a distance. Distance 0 means identical. But you are right, the plotting logic is flawed. But by any means, it is not a proper distance matrix. Too many 0s.

Comment: Yes, the docs are reasonably clear on the form of the matrix. Though not on what would happen if you used `inf`

Comment: This is similarity matrix, @Anony-Mousse.
0 means completely dissimilar and 1 means copy exact.

My intention is to compare the similarity between source code (plagiarism).

Comment: kmedoids expects **distances, not similarities**. 0 is identical to kmedoids!

Comment: Which clustering algorithm I could use to compare similarity between files, @Anony-Mousse?

Comment: Try d=1-sim it may just work for you. Try other such mappings, too.

Answer (score 0):

For part 2 of your question you have only 11 unique points if you only take the first two values in the second dimension of distances. i.e.

```
[[ 0.     0.84 ]
 [ 0.84   0.   ]
 [ 0.86   0.71 ]
 [ 0.115  0.06 ]
 [ 0.15   0.125]
 [ 0.055  0.06 ]
 [ 0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.07   0.07 ]
 [ 0.065  0.065]
 [ 0.     0.   ] # duplicate
 [ 0.165  0.165]
 [ 0.     0.   ] # duplicate
 [ 0.     0.   ] # duplicate
 [ 0.     0.   ] # duplicate
 [ 0.065  0.07 ]]
```

I'm not sure if that helps with your first problem but maybe it indicates that the contents of distances is in a different form from what you are expecting?